# It’s hidden, but there

Tags: rebus

Sorry, I’m really really bad at drawing, but I managed to somehow draw this rebus:

[image: haha the stack imgur thing says faols (fails!)]

(My friend posted this a minute ago, then deleted it because he forgot that we agreed that I’m going to be posting it)

Comment: Oooh, this looks fun, but I am just wondering what the last word on the card is? :)

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie maybe it says LENNY? Hahah, I don't know either :P

Comment: It says legal, but it doesn’t matter that much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it:

> Hidden sir?

Reasoning:

> They said hi.

Also:

> A burrow is a den.

And:

> The person was called sir.

Finally:

> ID is id as in h**id**den

Comment: Wow! There’s no sir in it but you did well!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it's

> Heidi Denser.  But I have no idea who that is, so that may be a problem

Because

> Hello = Hi
>  that's a picture "ID"  So Hi+ID = Heidi

And then

> An animals underground lair = DEN 
>  and SIR   DEN+SIR = Denser

Comment: Upvote for somehow getting this wow